# Read Multiple rows from Random CSV data config in jmeter

Tags: csv, variables, post, jmeter

I want to fetch multiple values from my CSV file and my CSV files look like this but it has hundreds of rows:

Name, Pass, ID, a_ID, f_ID
xyz1, pas1, i1, a_01, f_01
xyz2, pas2, i2, a_02, f_02
xyz3, pas3, i3, a_03, f_03
xyz4, pas4, i4, a_04, f_04
..
and so on.

The call I want to make needs to have multiple values accessed at the same time.

so in my body data I want to access multiple row values from above like this:

```
[
{
    "Name":"${Name}", //value = xyz1
    "Pass": ${Pass}, //value = pass1
    "ID": ${ID}, //value = i1
    "a_ID": "${a_ID}", //value = a_id1
    "f_ID": ${f_ID} //value = f_id1
},
{
    "Name":"${Name}", //value = xyz2
    "Pass": ${Pass}, //value = pass2
    "ID": ${ID}, //value = i2
    "a_ID": "${a_ID}", //value = a_id2
    "f_ID": ${f_ID} //value = f_id2
},
{
    "Name":"${Name}", //value = xyz3
    "Pass": ${Pass}, //value = pass3
    "ID": ${ID}, //value = i3
    "a_ID": "${a_ID}", //value = a_id3
    "f_ID": ${f_ID} //value = f_id3
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to achieve your goal using any of JMeter's [configuration elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) (including [plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)), if you want to build request body dynamically from file you will have to go for [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).

Example code:

```
def payload = []
new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().eachWithIndex { line, index ->
    if (index > 0) {
        def entries = line.split(',')
        def entry = [:]
        entry.put('Name', entries[0])
        entry.put('Pass', entries[1])
        entry.put('ID', entries[2])
        entry.put('a_ID', entries[3])
        entry.put('f_ID', entries[4])
        payload.add(entry)
    }
}

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

If everything goes well you should be able to access generated value as `${payload}` where required

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)